Telethon doesn't connect with the Web Auth Key
I am trying to perform a request as
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon.crypto import AuthKey
import binascii
import asyncio

# Your parameters
api_id = ""
api_hash = ""
auth_key_hex = ""
session = StringSession()
session.auth_key = AuthKey(data=bytearray.fromhex(auth_key_hex))
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.connect()
asyncio.run(main())

The code is freezes and doesn't go futher of await client.connect(). Eventually, It doesn't connect me. What should I do? Is the server salt essential in a request?
